# How to use gyroscope to get the distance between two close points in augmented reality?

Tags: iphone, augmented-reality

I would like to know is there any possible way to get the distance between two points which are closely located by using gyroscope.I am using camera to point two points in the screen on the floor .I would like to get the distance between two points .Is there any method to get the same

Comment: i have tried it.I dont want to get the distance between toe geo point

Comment: visit this :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379902/accurately-measuring-relative-distance-between-a-set-of-fiducials-augmented-rea